# Android SQLite 3 tutorial

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

So I have a database named `db.sqlite3`. And I work on an Android project. I need to do some query on it.

I have a lot of questions about it - is there a good tutorial?

Most importantly, where did I put the database? (It's not to big in the project but which folder?)

How do I do a query?

(When I googed it, I didn't find anything relevant.)

Comment: Tutorials on the main [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) website were not helpful?  I found the [Notepad](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) tutorial to be useful when it came to basic DB interactions.

Comment: a good sqlite android tutorial to start http://www.quicktips.in/basic-android-sqlite-database-exampletutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the database in the assets folder. At runtime you can access it like this:

```
InputStream db = activityContext.getAssets().open("db.sqlite3");
```

You can write it wherever you want, but it is better to store it in the `/data/data/%app_package_name%/databases` folder.

Then extend SQLiteOpenHelper and pass "db.sqlite3" as the name argument:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

Later, you can `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()` and issue queries on the returned objects.

Comment: eclipse doesn't recognize activityContext ... And i didn't understand what you mean here "you can write it wherever you want, but it is better to store it in /data/data/%app_package_name%/databases folder"

Comment: acivityContext is an instance of any activity, but it also can be an instance of your app. You don't know how to work with streams?

Comment: Sorry but it's the first time i try to do that can you be more explicit please. And yes i don't know how to work with streams.